# Best way to avoid deadlocks from triggers? Non-clustered index? SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2012, deadlock

I have a table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Log_File
(
    Hostname CHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    Line_Number INT NOT NULL, 
    Log_Line VARCHAR(8000) NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT pk_Log_File PRIMARY KEY (Hostname, Line_Number)
)
```

Each server is bulk inserting about 1000 rows every 5 seconds. Whenever there is a bulk insert, a trigger runs on the `INSERTED` table and it iterates through the `log_line` records with a cursor and updates another table.

When I only have one server writing to the `Log_File` table, I have no issues.  When I try have 20 servers writing to the table at the same time, I occasionally get a deadlock error and the transaction closes on some of the machines, killing the thread.

This is usually a problem when I start up the application on each server because it has to scan the `Log_File` table to find the `MAX(Line_Number)` for itself so it knows where to begin reading its own log file from.

I haven't set an index on this table. Would creating a clustered or nonclustered index help the situation? Unfortunately a cursor is absolutely necessary since I need to iterate through each record in order to deal with islands and gaps.

Any help on reducing deadlocks or making this faster is appreciated!

Comment: The problem is that awful cursor you are using to update another table. Rewrite your logic into a set based update and the locking will go away. You say it required but I bet it can done without RBAR.

Comment: And YES an index will help. When you have a table with no clustered index it is called a heap and they can have massive performance problems.

Comment: Doesn't the primary key default to creating a clustered index?

Comment: Yes it does. You said you didn't have any indexes, I didn't look back at the table definition. So obviously you do have a clustered index right there in your ddl. Your locking is 100% a by product of RBAR on 1,000 rows every 5 seconds. Get rid of the problem (the cursor) and it will correct the symptom (deadlocking). I would be very surprised if a set based solution can't be created for an update statement.